# How can I dynamically add input fields in visual force on a button click?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, wrapper-class

I want to add a button "ADD NEW RECORD". When the button is clicked, a new row for input fields of accounts should be added along with the checkbox wrapped with it.
How can this be done?
EDIT:
Also, is there a way by which only selected accounts get updated and not the whole data? Thanks in advance.

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="wrapAccountAndCheckbox" tabStyle="Account" >

    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Records">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Name </th>            
                    <th> Fax </th>
                    <th> Phone </th>
                </tr>

                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapClassList}" var="accountTable" id="Acnt_Table">

                    <tr>
                        <td> <apex:inputField value="{!accountTable.actWrap.Name}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:inputField value="{!accountTable.actWrap.fax}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:inputField value="{!accountTable.actWrap.phone}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accountTable.flag}"/> </td>
                    </tr>



                </apex:repeat>
            </table>  


            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!save}" />
                 <apex:commandButton value="DELETE" action="{!deleteAcc}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

CONTROLLER WITH WRAPPER CLASS

```
public class wrapAccountAndCheckbox {

    public List<wrapperClass> wrapClassList{get;set;}
    public List<Account> actList;
    public wrapperClass wc{get;set;}
    List<account> wcList=new List<account>();


    public wrapAccountAndCheckbox(){
        wrapClassList = new List<wrapperClass>();
        actList = new List<Account>();
        actList = [SELECT Id, Name, Fax, Phone FROM Account];
        For(Account ac : actList){
            wc = new wrapperClass();
            wc.flag = false;
            wc.actWrap = ac;
            wrapClassList.add(wc);
        }
    }
    public class wrapperClass{
        public boolean flag{get;set;}
        public Account actWrap{get;set;}


    }

    public void updateDetails()
    {
        if(wrapClassList!=null)
        {   wcList.clear();
            for(wrapperClass wc: wrapClassList)
            {   if(wc.flag==true)
            {wcList.add(wc.actWrap);
            }
            }        
        }
    }
    public pageReference save()
    {updateDetails();   
     update wcList;
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://cunning-badger-419701-dev-ed--c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/AccountActions');
     return pageRef;
    }

    public pageReference deleteAcc()
    {
        updateDetails();
        try{
            for(Account a:actList)
            {   if(wcList.contains(a))
                delete a;}
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Exception in Delete>>>>'+e);
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://cunning-badger-419701-dev-ed--c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/AccountActions');
        return pageRef;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common requirement.  First add a Add row button with ypur table

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addNewRow}" rerender="frm" Status="status" immediate="true" />
```

and then in your controller add row in existing list

```
public void addNewRow() {
    wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();
    wc.flag = false;
    wc.actWrap = new Account();
    wrapClassList.add(wc);
}
```